# Openerp edit default tag search

Tags: odoo

So in openerp when you search for a customer tag it returns all the customers that have that tag, or customers who have that tag and other tags.

For example when I search customers that have the tag "Prospect" I only want those customers to show up and not customers that have "Prospect"/"Leads"

I thought editing res.partner.select would do the trick but it hasn't helped. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're looking for is the name_search function, you have to override it and develop your functionality.

Here is a link with documentation:
https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html